# Logging PayPal payments in application

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have several ambiguities in using paypal methods and cases, when IPN messages are sent. Im developing app, in which im using paypal(sandbox) for making deposits and cashouts. Each of these both transactions I want to log in my app and here some obscurity raises becouse I need to capture as many cases that may occur. So I'll take it gradually and I'll be thankful also for each partial response.

Firstly, I have some general questions:

In my app, im using *BuyNow button*, AdaptivePayment methods *PAY* and *PaymentDetails* and Merchant method *GetTransactionDetails*. Are these methods part of Bussines account and for free (there are no monthly fees) right? I cant afford to pay some monthly fees from begining.

May arise any problems, when i'll deploy it to non-sanbox environment?

**cashout**

For cashout Im using Adaptive payment PAY method.

1. When My app client make a cashout to his/her paypal account, I can catch through IPN message, that payment is completed and using AdaptivePayment *PaymentDetails* method and Merchant *GetTransactionDetails* method I can find out, that there is pending status with paymentreview reason.  So on receiver side, where I dont have access, is payment review possibility. Thus receiver can DENY payment and here is a question, how to get information about this user action, becouse an IPN message doesn't come.
2. Another case that im facing is when client of my app make cashout to
   his/her bussines paypal account with different currency from sender
   (my bussines paypal account). There is pending status too, but with
   reason "multicurrency" in IPN message. Here is similar problem to
   previous point 1)... again, I cant get IPN message, which
   determine, if user accepted or not the transacion.

**deposit**

For deposit Im using PayPal standard Buy now button.

1. PAYER SIDE(my app client): I dont understand, why there is payment
   review (accept/deny) in payer account profile, when status of
   payment is completed? Is it common behavior only in sandbox
   environment? Or is it possible accept/deny payment on payer side in
   non-sandbox?
2. RECEIVER SIDE(my bussines paypal account): There is payment review
   too, on receiver side, and if im right, these links (accept/deny)
   are similar to links on payer side, arent? There is refund
   posibility too, exists some API method to refund programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, each of the products you mentioned do not have a monthly fee.

If a user accepts or denies a pending payment that would trigger another IPN with the completed status.  Are you saying you've tested this specifically and you're seeing otherwise?

Receivers would only have to accept/deny in cases where there is currency conversion or maybe they have fraud filters set to flag specific transactions, etc.  In most cases there should be no review necessary.

Comment: Yea, I just tested it. Using Buy now button, when my bussines account is receiver and i accept/deny payment, IPN message is received. But using adaptive payment PAY method, when receiver is my app client's personal or businnes account and he accept/deny payment of pending reason payment review or multicurrency, new IPN message won't come.